# PHP decrypt encrypted text with salt,key and iv

Tags: php, android, encryption

In my Android application, I can encrypt simple texts like this:

```
String     key        = "YourKey";
String     salt       = "YourSalt";
byte[]     iv         = new byte[16];
Encryption encryption = Encryption.getDefault(key, salt, iv);
String encrypted = encryption.encryptOrNull("Text to be encrypt");
Log.e("encrypted text ", encrypted);
```

I'm utilizing this [library](https://github.com/simbiose/Encryption).

Now after I encrypt the text, I want to decrypt it by PHP. Is there any solutions to do that?

Comment: What did you use in the end?

Answer (score 2):

That library seems to be Java-only and has no ports to other languages. The documentation is very sparse about the algorithm, so it's not quite easy to write a PHP equivalent for it. That's no use for you.

You need to utilize a library that <del>either</del> implements a standard algorithm like <del>[RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem))</del> [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), <del>or has bindings for PHP, like [MCrypt](https://github.com/serpro/Android-PHP-Encrypt-Decrypt)</del>.

**Update**: As [@LukePark suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406621/php-decrypt-encrypted-text-with-salt-key-and-iv/41406757?noredirect=1#comment70025123_41406757) in the comments, [mcrypt is insecure](https://lodge.statamic.com/questions/1162-mcrypt-usage-is-insecure) and should be avoided.

**Update**: As [@zaph clarifies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406621/php-decrypt-encrypted-text-with-salt-key-and-iv/41406757?noredirect=1#comment72834712_41406757) in the comments, An asymmetric algorithm like RSA is not suitable for encrypting data, generally a symmetric encryption algorithm such as AES is used for data.

Comment: Mcrypt has been deprecated for years and doesn't support PKCS5 padding.

Comment: Yeah, better. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Text and data is rarely encrypted with RSA (an asymmetric encryption algorithm) because the data size is limited to less than the key length and it is very slow. Generally a symmetric encryption algorithm such as AES is used for data.

Comment: @zaph, Thank you for the clarification. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found [**RNCryptor**](https://github.com/RNCryptor) library which seems to be a good choice (I need to test it more).

**AES** file format with implementations in many languages.
**Current list of languages supported:**

> Java, PHP, Ruby, Swift, JavaScript, Phyton, Objective-C, Haskell,
>   Rust, C, C++, C#, Erlang, Go

https://github.com/RNCryptor

- **PHP** : https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-php
- **Java** : https://github.com/RNCryptor/JNCryptor

Comment: It also supports key derivation, authentication and versioning.